# Total value of sum of integers does not equal calculated value

Tags: java, c

While doing unsigned int conversions in Java I got some "anomalous" results, which I have cut down to the minimal case shown below. The same code in C generates similar results.

The problem is that when I calculate the theoretical sum of the absolute value of all integer values using the Gauss summation formula n(n+1)/2 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) the value I calculate does not match the total if I actually add up all the absolute values one by one.

Note that when I calculate the total using the summation formula the division by 2 "/2" is omitted because I am adding both the negative and positive numbers as absolute values, and at the end I have to add (longIntegerMax + 1) because the negative numbers have one extra number at the end (Integer.MIN) which has the absolute value of Integer.MAX + 1.

```
public static void main( String[] asArguments ){
    long longAbsoluteTotal = 0;
    long longNumberOfIntegers = 0;
    long longIntegerMax = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    long longIntegerMin = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for( int i = Integer.MIN_VALUE;; i++ ){
        longNumberOfIntegers++;
        if( i < 0 ){
            longAbsoluteTotal += i * -1;
        } else {
            longAbsoluteTotal += i;
        }
        if( i == Integer.MAX_VALUE ) break;
    }
    long longCalculatedTotal = longIntegerMax * (longIntegerMax + 1) + longIntegerMax + 1; 
    System.out.println( "count of all integers: " + longNumberOfIntegers ); 
    System.out.println( "total of absolute value of all integers: " + longAbsoluteTotal );
    System.out.println( "calculated total of absolute value of all integers: " + longCalculatedTotal );
}
```

output:

```
 count of all integers: 4294967296
 total of absolute value of all integers: 4611686014132420608
 calculated total of absolute value of all integers: 4611686018427387904
```

As you can see, the calculated total is close to the real total, but does not match it exactly. Why not?

Comment: Side note: `if( i < 0 ) longAbsoluteTotal -= i;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is here ..

```
longAbsoluteTotal += i * -1;
```

The `( i * -1 )` is still integer arithmetic, it produces a number greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE and overflows back to Integer.MIN_VALUE;

You could fix this as @Evgeniy suggested, or you could use

```
longAbsoluteTotal += i * -1L;
```

to force long arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for( int i = Integer.MIN_VALUE;; i++ ){
```

to

```
for( long i = Integer.MIN_VALUE;; i++ ){
```

all will be OK

It's similar to -Integer.MIN_VALUE == -2147483648

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at... but could you explain _why_ this fixes the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
4611686014132420608 - 4611686018427387904 = -4294967296 = Integer.MIN_VALUE * 2
```

The reason is that

```
Integer.MIN_VALUE * -1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

Since we use two's complement to represent negative value.

The two's complement of Integer.MIN_VALUE(0x80000000) = 0x7fffffff + 0x1 = 0x80000000.